Is there any way to use 'OVERRIDING SYSTEM VALUE' when importing data from CSV using liquibase & PostgreSQL
I'm importing data from CSV using Liquibase and would like to Import values using the 'OVERRIDING SYSTEM VALUE' option, is this possible?
- loadData:
    tableName: TABLE
    file: xyz.CSV

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: cannot insert a non-DEFAULT value into column "id"
Detail: Column "id" is an identity column defined as GENERATED ALWAYS.
Hint: Use OVERRIDING SYSTEM VALUE to override.

That's not supported by Liquibase - it will not append or modify the inserts as per source file.
